# como puedo poner precio a productos de mi lista que se llamen igual

Tags: vba

una ayuda por favor tengo una tabla de excel con 2000 productos de estos muchos se repiten o y lo que yo quiero es ponerles un precio, pero no ir uno por uno si no escogen el precio y se ponga en todos los que son iguales.
por ejemplo:
casa de cristal
casa de madera
carrito Plastico
avion pequeño
casa de tela
entonces quiero que todos los que se llamen casa tengan el mismo precio

Answer (score 0):

Puedes Primeor filtrar la lista para el producto, para esto usa el filtro propio de excel

Y luego usar una funcion SI propia de excel

Ejemplo

SI(C2="casa de cristal";1000)

Esto se refiere a que  SI(C2 = casa de cristal; entonces devolver un 1000 en la casilla correspondiente)

Comment: Hola, tengo una duda lo que hice fue hacer una búsqueda dinámica para visualizar los elementos iguales, pero una vez que los filtre no puedo poner el mismo valor que quiero

Comment: Qué has programado? Edita tu pregunta, hazla más clara y pon el código que hayas probado.

Comment: Hola Roberto lograste solucionar ?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que picar a mano los precios al menos una vez, ya que formularlo con SIES si tienes muchos productos es un infierno. Necesitas crearte manualmente una lista en la que cada producto aparezca una sola vez y su precio.

Luego puedes relacionar esa lista con tus datos repetidos con un BUSCARV:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi fórmula en la columna B es: `=BUSCARV(A1;$E$2:$F$4;2;FALSO)`